# Portability of OCaml bytecode

Tags: ocaml, bytecode, endianness

I compile an OCaml program in bytecode on an x86 machine, and transfer the bytecode to a ppc64 machine. Assuming  that the ppc64 machine has ocamlrun (compiled for ppc64), will I be able to execute my program on the ppc64 architecture ? Is it that simple ?

In other terms, is the bytecode resistant to endianness ?

If not, then what is the purpose of the bytecode ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume you don't need any external function; otherwise of course you need the binary code providing them.

Yes, the bytecode is resistant to endianness (and to word size), for systems supported by Ocaml.

<sup>(however, your bytecode may depend upon the particular version of `ocamlrun` interpreter and the `Pervasives` module used by your program; hence, a bytecode for Ocaml 4.01 might not run in Ocaml 4.02 runtime or vice versa; YMMV)</sup>

In particular when you build Ocaml from [its source code](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml), it is compiling itself with a distributed version (in [`boot/` subdirectory](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/tree/trunk/boot) ...) of `ocamlc` - which is a bytecode file.

And Ocaml folks badly need that portability, since most of the Ocaml compiler is written in Ocaml itself and is [bootstrapped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_%28compilers%29).

See also J.Pitrat's blog on [*meta-bugs, curse of the bootstrap*](http://bootstrappingartificialintelligence.fr/WordPress3/2014/06/the-meta-bug-curse-of-the-bootstrap/) which indirectly explains why updating that `boot/ocamlc` file has to be done rarely and carefully by Ocaml team. Within the Ocaml code, `make bootstrap` has to be done occasionally and very carefully (at least to commit a newer version of `boot/ocamlc` bytecode file).